# JSON to R for Data Mining

Tags: json, r, data-mining

I am trying to grab tweets using the Topsy Otter api, so I can perform some data mining on it for my dissertation.

So far, I have got:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
tweet_data <- getURL("http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=PSN&mintime=1301634000&perpage=10&maxtime=1304226000&apikey=xxx")
fromJSON(tweet_data)
```

Which works fine. Now however, I want to return just a couple details from this file, 'content' and 'trackback_date'. I cannot seem to figure out how - I have tried cobbling a couple of examples together, but unable to extract what I want.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
trackback_date <- lapply(tweet_data$result, function(x){x$trackback_date})

content <- lapply(tweet_data$result, function(x){x$content})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**edit**
I have also tried:

```
library("rjson")
# use rjson

tweet_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=PSN&mintime=1301634000&perpage=10&maxtime=1304226000&apikey=xxx"), collapse=""))
# get a data from Topsy Otter API
# convert JSON data into R object using fromJSON()

trackback_date <- lapply(tweet_data$result, function(x){x$trackback_date})

content <- lapply(tweet_data$result, function(x){x$content})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic processing of Topsy Otter API response:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
tweet_data <- getURL("http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=PSN&mintime=1301634000&perpage=10&maxtime=1304226000&apikey=xxx")

#
# Addition to your code
#
tweets <- fromJSON(tweet_data)$response$list
content <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$content)
trackback_date <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$trackback_date)
```

**EDIT: Processing multiple pages**

Function gets 100 items from specified `page`:

```
pagetweets <- function(page){
  url <- paste("http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=PSN&mintime=1301634000&page=",page,
               "&perpage=100&maxtime=1304226000&apikey=xxx",
               collapse="", sep="")
  tweet_data <- getURL(url)
  fromJSON(tweet_data)$response$list
}
```

Now we can apply it to multiple pages:

```
tweets <- unlist(lapply(1:10, pagetweets), recursive=F)
```

And, voila, this code:

```
content <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$content)
trackback_date <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$trackback_date)
```

returns you 1000 records.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. Could you explain what is going on here?

Comment: `fromJSON` processes `tweet_data` and returns `list` with two elements: `request` and `response`. In turn, `response` is a list with eight elements among which we are interested in `list`. Thus, `fromJSON(tweet_data)$response$list` gives us list with raw data. Then we extract its elements with `sapply`.

Comment: Thank you redmond. How might I go about doing numerous 'gets'? I.e each geturl returns 100 tweets, if I wanted to do this 10 times to get 1000 tweets, how would I go about adding them all into one 'tweet_data'?

Comment: Well, you should place basic routine in function that returns list of tweets and then `merge` them.

Comment: @Coffee, please, see EDIT in the answer